# SQL Compact Bulk Update table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, bulkupdate

I've hit a little problem.  I'm Inserting/Updating over 2k of records and within the 2k, there may be some record that I already have.  The once I have already I may need to update the original record etc.

The solution uses SQL Compact and it can run on slow computers.  I did have a method, but it took over 10 mins. (Way too long).

So now I do a bulk insert into a temp table, then I can do a insert from the temp to the original.

I seem to have an issue with my update script.  The below script works with SQL Server, but when I attempt the same script (with the same database schema etc), it does not work.

Can anyone help?

```
UPDATE Clients 
SET     Title = Temp_Clients.Title
       ,Forename = Temp_Clients.Forename
       ,Surname = Temp_Clients.Surname
       ,DOB = Temp_Clients.DOB
       ,IsMale = Temp_Clients.IsMale
       ,Address1 = Temp_Clients.Address1
       ,Address2 =Temp_Clients.Address2
       ,Address3 = Temp_Clients.Address3
       ,Town = Temp_Clients.Town
       ,County = Temp_Clients.County
       ,Postcode = Temp_Clients.Postcode
       ,Telephone = Temp_Clients.Telephone
       ,Mobile = Temp_Clients.Mobile
       ,Email =Temp_Clients.Email
     ,LocationID = Temp_Clients.LocationID
    ,GpPractice = Temp_Clients.GpPractice
     ,GpName = Temp_Clients.GpName
FROM Temp_Clients 
INNER JOIN Clients AS A ON A.[CustomClientID] = Temp_Clients.[CustomClientID]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your from is the wrong way around: It should be client first then joining on the temp_clients.

```
UPDATE Clients 
SET     Title = Temp_Clients.Title
       ,Forename = Temp_Clients.Forename
       ,Surname = Temp_Clients.Surname
       ,DOB = Temp_Clients.DOB
       ,IsMale = Temp_Clients.IsMale
       ,Address1 = Temp_Clients.Address1
       ,Address2 =Temp_Clients.Address2
       ,Address3 = Temp_Clients.Address3
       ,Town = Temp_Clients.Town
       ,County = Temp_Clients.County
       ,Postcode = Temp_Clients.Postcode
       ,Telephone = Temp_Clients.Telephone
       ,Mobile = Temp_Clients.Mobile
       ,Email =Temp_Clients.Email
     ,LocationID = Temp_Clients.LocationID
    ,GpPractice = Temp_Clients.GpPractice
     ,GpName = Temp_Clients.GpName
FROM Clients INNER JOIN Temp_Clients ON Clients.[CustomClientID] = Temp_Clients.[CustomClientID]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sadly its still not working.

I get the below error

FROM Clients INNER JOIN Temp_Clients ON Clients.[CustomClientID] = Temp_Clients.[CustomClientID]
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 19,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = FROM ]

Comment: Ah sorry with SQL server compact you cannot use that type of query http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174122(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of any other way I could do what I need with SQL Compact?

Comment: I think your only option is to do a Insert and Delete instead of update.